# XCode 14.1 compatibility with Unity 17.1

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a very old Unity project that I'm upgrading to 17.1 to avoid porting the UnityScript code (for the time being). I'm then looking to build the project for iOS. From my understanding, I need XCode 14.1. Will the build created by Unity 17.1 still be compatible with XCode 14.1, or will I run into issues?

I've hunted around for answers to the question but haven't found any definitive solutions. I'm trying to avoid wasting time upgrading the project to find out that there will be compatability issues.

Comment: You may or may not run into issues with Xcode, but you may still be rejected when you submit to the app store because of things like `UIWebView` and other issues that have been resolved in newer Unity versions to comply with Apple rule changes. There are similar issues with Android builds if you plan to do that too.